# Skipping Feature - SpecFlow C#

Tags: c#, nunit, specflow

I'm looking to intercept a test using the [BeforeFeature] [SpecFlow Hook](http://specflow.org/) and ignore the entire feature file.

```
private static string FeatureName = FeatureContext.Current.FeatureInfo.Title;

[BeforeFeature]
public static void BeforeFeature()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before feature");

    if (TestFilter.ShouldBeIgnored(FeatureName))
    {
        // Ignore Feature if it matches TestFilter Requirements
    }
}
```

Comment: @k-treanor - You have a statement followed by a code sample, but I don't see what question you're asking.

Comment: Added SpecFlow link and removed excess blank lines from code example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Specflow + Nunit, you can call

```
Assert.Ignore("ignore message here");
```

This will cause the individual tests to be ignored, if their feature is ran.
However, this may require you to use a BeforeScenario hook instead of a BeforeFeature hook.

Because BeforeScenario has access to the feature info, this should not be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look into @ignore tag? You can skip features or scenarios.
[link](https://specflow.org/documentation/Test-result/#ignored-tests/)

Comment: You did not read his question.
He has custom logic that needs to run and ignore the test programmatically.
@ignore is a static piece of text that requires a human to place it there at design time.
He wants to decide on ignoring the test at run time.

Comment: The link is no longer valid.