# Is it possible to ignore Firefox for running the feature?

Tags: selenium, firefox, specflow

I am trying to use tags for ignoring Firefox for running few feature files.

I mean something like:

```
@Browser_Chrome


Feature: My Functionality


@ignore @Browser_Firefox

Scenario: 

Given blablabla"
```

Is it possible?
Now looks like @ignore tag is working in any way

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: What unit test framework are you using in conjunction with SpecFlow? I found [Skipping Feature - SpecFlow C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50135126/3092298). The answers suggest using the `@ignore` tag like you are trying to use, and also `Assert.Ignore(...)`, but this is specific to the NUnit library.

Comment: Sorry for delay!
It is NUnit and Selenium

Answer (score 0):

You can always check within your tests using getCapabilities(https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html#getCapabilities--):

```
    assumeTrue( !(driver as RemoteWebDriver).capabilities
    .getCapability("browserName").equals("firefox") ) )
```

More info about assume: https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assume.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run almost all tests on Firefox, but want to exclude some. I would use a tag with a matching beforescenario which does the ignoring.

Feature file:

```
@BeforeExcludeFF @ThisIsMyFeature
Scenario: Dont run this when the browser is Firefox
Given blablabla
When blablabla 
Then blablabla
```

Code behind:

```
    [BeforeScenario("BeforeExcludeFF", Order = 1)]
    public void BeforeExcludeFF()
    {
        // we need to get the current browser to know if it is firefox
        ICapabilities capabilities = ((RemoteWebDriver)driver).Capabilities;
        string browser = capabilities.GetCapability("browserName");     

        if(browser.ToLower() == "firefox")
        {
            // don't forget to log WHY we ignore this scenario on FF
            LogToConsoleAndIgnore(@"We dont want to run this scenario because ");
        }
    }

    private void LogToConsoleAndIgnore(string reason)
    {            
        Console.WriteLine(reason);
        Assert.Ignore(reason);
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you!!
It works (but I use "capabilities.GetCapability("browserName")" instead capabilities.BrowserName.ToString())

Comment: Ah yes, that seems to be the new implementation for getcapabilities. Don't forget to mark this question as answered

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't amount of reputation for marking your answer as right ((
Hope I will do it later